# Why can't I use は with ある?

Tags: particles, subjects

I wanted to say: there is a pen. Hence, I said

> ペンはある

But my girlfriend said to me that one has to say:

> ペンがある。

But she can't explain to me why, and I don't understand.

Do you have an explanation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We usually say 「XX**は**ある(よ)」(は=topic particle) etc when replying to 「XXはある?」"Is there XX?", and 「XX**が**ある(よ)」(が=subject particle) when replying to 「何がある(の)?」"What's there?"

Comment: When it comes to understanding wa vs ga, I think it helps (at least in my own learning experience) to set aside existing notions from the framework of a subject-prominent language (such as English). Japanese is a topic-prominent language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic-prominent_language). The feature doesn't really exist in, say, English.

Answer (score 4):

I feel that the distinctions between は and が are one of the hardest parts to learn about the Japanese language, so I'll try to keep things mostly focused on this example.

> ペンはある

Here "は” marks ”ペン" as a "topic", rather a "subject", but what that really translates into is a feeling of:

> There *is* a pen (but there isn't a ....)

This is because that "は" also is commonly used to indicate that what follows it applies to the thing before the は, but *not* to something else which may or may not be directly stated.

Here is an example where the thing that doesn't apply is directly stated:

> ペンはあるけど、鉛筆はない

In fact は tends to be used more frequently with negative verbs (hence the は part of ではない). So if you are saying "the pen isn't there", this would be completely natural:

> ペンはない

However, if there was a situation where someone was panicking and somebody asked them "What is wrong?" (どうしたの？), they could very well reply using が instead:

> ペンがないよ！

This is because が strongly emphasizes the subject, and is generally used when there was some uncertainty about a subject which is being clarified.

Comment: The reason why you use が (or save topicalization) in the last example is because it's a sentence of neutral description rather than emphasis by a sentence of exclusion. In short, you can't rephrase it as  ないのはペンだよ.

Answer (score 3):

That would be 「ペン**が**ある。」 100% of the time.

「ペン**が**ある。」 (= "There is a pen.") is a statement about 'what is there' or 'what the speaker has just found at a particular location".  It is ***not*** a statement that gives some kind of description about either pens in general or a particular pen.

If you desire to make a further statement about the pen ***after*** you have found it and said 「ペン**が**ある。」, you can use 「**は**」 as in 「そのペン**は**とても[長]{なが}い。」= "The pen is very long." and such .

「ペン**は**ある。」, as a stand-alone statement, sounds ***far more weird*** to us Japanese-speakers than you could probably imagine at this stage.  You could look like you were trying a make a profound philosophical statement about pens in general.  I call that the power of particles - "POP" for short.  Learning Japanese means learning POP.

If you go outside of your house and find a dog right in front of you, you will say 「イヌ**が**いる。」.  If you said 「イヌ**は**いる。」 instead, people would wonder if you were OK because you would look as if you were making a metaphysical statement about dogs and the universe outside of your front door on your way to Burger King.